# Custom Liquibase executor combining JdbcExecutor and LoggingExecutor

Tags: liquibase

I'm looking for a way to record and write all those SQL statements to an output 
file which get executed while running a Liquibase migration against an empty
target database.

The idea behind this is to speed up the initialization phase of integration tests 
against a test database by simply reading and executing the SQL statements from the
generated file for subsequent tests.

I had no luck using updateSQL due to different handling of changesets with 
pre-conditions (e.g. changeSetExecuted resolves to true for "update" but false for 
"updateSQL").

Another approach was to run the Liquibase migration first, then writing a temporary
changelog file using GenerateChangeLogCommand which is finally used by another Liquibase
instance to produce an SQL update file.

While this approach works, it a) feels a bit hacky-ish, b) the end result is not the same
as running the migration directly.

Anyway, what I've come up with is a custom implementation of JdbcExecutor which incorporates
a LoggingExecutor. The implementation looks as follows:

```
@LiquibaseService(skip = true)
public class LoggingJdbcExecutor extends JdbcExecutor {

    private LoggingExecutor loggingExecutor;

    public LoggingJdbcExecutor(Database database, Writer writer) {
        loggingExecutor = new LoggingExecutor(this, writer, database);
        setDatabase(database);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(SqlStatement sql, List<SqlVisitor> sqlVisitors) throws DatabaseException {
        super.execute(sql, sqlVisitors);
        loggingExecutor.execute(sql, sqlVisitors);
    }

    @Override
    public int update(SqlStatement sql, List<SqlVisitor> sqlVisitors) throws DatabaseException {
    final int result = super.update(sql, sqlVisitors);
        loggingExecutor.update(sql, sqlVisitors);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void comment(String message) throws DatabaseException {
        super.comment(message);
        loggingExecutor.comment(message);
    }
}
```

This executor gets injected into Liquibase before update() is invoked as follows:

```
final String path = configuration.getUpdateSqlExportFile();
ExecutorService.getInstance().setExecutor(liquibase.getDatabase(), new LoggingJdbcExecutor(
    liquibase.getDatabase(), new FileWriter(path)
));
```

Is this approach reasonable and future proof ? While it seems to work I'm not sure if maybe I'm
missing something and there's a better way.

Thanks